# Class variable in Concern Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a concern to encapsulate the logic to upload images for some resources of my application, let's say for example that there's an image associated with each course, and the same for every user.

```
module Picturable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      PATH_IMAGE = File.join Rails.root,"public","#{table_name}_imgs"
      after_save :save_image
    end
  def photo=(file)
    unless file.blank?
      @file = file
      self.extension = file.original_filename.split(".").last.downcase
    end
  end
  def path_image
    File.join PATH_IMAGE, "#{self.id}.#{self.extension}"
  end
  def path_img
    "/#{self.class.table_name}_imgs/#{self.id}.#{self.extension}"
  end

  def has_image?
    File.exists? path_image
  end

  private
  def save_image
    unless @file.nil?
        FileUtils.mkdir_p PATH_IMAGE

        File.open(path_image, "wb") do |f|

            f.write(@file.read)
        end
        @file =nil
    end
  end
end
```

I have edited the code because some of the methods were in spanish, the concern works as expected but the problem is with the **table_name** variable, I haven't been able to understand how the value changes, sometimes it gets the value of users, sometimes the value of courses, but of course sometimes I get errors because the framework search the image of users in the folder of courses and vice versa.

The way I'm including the Concern looks as follow:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Picturable
end
```

I want to include the concern in each model that is going to have in image associated, but I need to save the images in different folders representing each one of the resources, let's say that users images should be saved in users_imgs folder, and courses's images should be saved in courses_imgs and so on.

Any clue in what am I doing wrong or if my approach is the wrong one.

Here is the error explained with the rails console:
[image: rails console session]

Thanks

Comment: What you have here looks fine. When are you actually getting errors, when you upload images?

Comment: Most of the times the path_image method returns "/courses_imgs/id.extension" even when I'm trying to access the method through a user object.
If later I re save the concern, it starts returning "/users_imgs/id.extension" as expected, but, then again if I upload a new image for the user, the concern comes back to return "/courses_imgs/id.extension". It works in a pretty weird way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your constant within the `included` block is being overwritten. You can get around this by using a method instead of a constant. Here's an example where I've defined a method called `image_root_path` which replaces the constant.

```
module Picturable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    after_save :save_image
  end

  def image_root_path
    File.join Rails.root,"public","#{self.class.table_name}_imgs"
  end

  def path_image
    File.join image_root_path, "#{self.id}.#{self.extension}"
  end

  # ...

  private
  def save_image
    unless @file.nil?
      FileUtils.mkdir_p image_root_path

      File.open(path_image, "wb") do |f|

        f.write(@file.read)
      end
      @file =nil
    end
  end
end
```